# Convert MySQL Datetime to C++ std::time_t

Tags: c++, mysql, datetime, time-t

I am stuck in a problem and really hope you can help me. I like to convert a MySQL `DATETIME` field into a C++ `std::time_t` variable. My database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE data(
    id              INTEGER       AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    path            VARCHAR(1000),
    acquisitionDate DATETIME
);
```

And I am trying to  save the value from `acquisitionDate` into a c++ variable of type `std::time_t`.

After some web searching I learned that I have to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` in my MySQL statement. However, I did not understand how to actual use it. I can generate a query and receive a `sql::ResultSet`:

```
std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(mConnection->createStatement());

std::string query="SELECT id, path, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acquisitionDate) FROM data WHERE id = 1";

std::unique_ptr<sql::ResultSet> res(stmt->executeQuery(query));
```

But I don't understand how I can get the actual field value into a `std::time_t` variable

```
if(res->next())
{
    std::time_t acquisitionDate =  res->getInt("acquisitionDate");
    std::time_t acquisitionDate =  res->???
}
```

Somehow my brain does not get this last step. Please help me.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also understood that it is possible to access the fields output by:

```
std::time_t acquisitionDate =  res->getInt("UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acquisitionDate)");
```

Or the SQL statement could rename the field:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acquisitionDate) AS foo FROM data WHERE id = 1
```

and then

```
std::time_t acquisitionDate =  res->getInt("foo");
```

However, casting should also be a good idea (after you have the correct field name):

```
std::time_t acquisitionDate =  static_cast<std::time_t>(res->getInt("foo"));
```

Comment: You can also use an alias `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(acquisitionDate) AS acquisitionDate` or get the int by index `res->getInt(2)`.

Comment: Life saver!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just cast it

`std::time_t acquisitionDate = (std::time_t)res->getInt("acquisitionDate");`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Casting is a good and quite easy idea. However, I figured out that my problem was understanding how to access the returned field. See my answer to this question